# Dropdown border to select (Flutter project)

Tags: flutter, dart

Hello I need to do a green border on this [image]

That's a DropdownButtonFormField and I can't change the color of the border yet I can change the background of it

I tried several things that I found but nothing works (I'm new to flutter).
I'm starting to flutter and I'm not yet familiar with widgets, thanks for ur help

````
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: AppColors.TERTIARY_COLOR,
          title: Text(
            AppLocalizations.of(context)!.text_upload_video_title_post_video,
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
          ),
          centerTitle: true,
        ),
        body: Form(
            key: _globalKey,
            child: ListView(
              keyboardDismissBehavior: ScrollViewKeyboardDismissBehavior.onDrag,
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 30),
              children: [
                SizedBox(height: 10),
                ElevatedButton.icon(
                  onPressed: () => chooseVideo(),
                  icon: Text(
                      AppLocalizations.of(context)!
                          .text_upload_video_choose_video,
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: AppColors.TERTIARY_COLOR,
                          fontSize: 14,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                  label: Visibility(
                      child: Icon(
                        Icons.check,
                        color: AppColors.TERTIARY_COLOR,
                      ),
                      visible: checkVideo),
                  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50.0)),
                      primary: Colors.transparent,
                      side: BorderSide(
                        width: 1,
                        color: AppColors.TERTIARY_COLOR,
                      ),
                      onPrimary: Colors.black,
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(
                        16.0,
                      )),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 10),
                ElevatedButton.icon(
                  onPressed: () => showAlertDialog(context),
                  icon: Text(
                      AppLocalizations.of(context)!
                          .text_upload_video_choose_image,
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: AppColors.TERTIARY_COLOR,
                          fontSize: 14,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                  label: Visibility(
                      child: Icon(
                        Icons.check,
                        color: AppColors.TERTIARY_COLOR,
                      ),
                      visible: checkImage),
                  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50.0)),
                      primary: Colors.transparent,
                      side: BorderSide(
                        width: 1,
                        color: AppColors.TERTIARY_COLOR,
                      ),
                      onPrimary: Colors.black,
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(
                        16.0,
                      )),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 10),
                SizedBox(height: 10),
                titleTextField(),
                FutureBuilder<List<DocumentsFolder>>(
                  future: _folders,
                  builder: (context, snapshot) {
                    if (snapshot.hasData) {
                      return Container(
                        color: Colors.transparent,
                        child: DropdownButtonFormField<DocumentsFolder>(
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                              borderSide: BorderSide(
                                color: AppColors.TERTIARY_COLOR,
                                width: 1,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          iconSize: 0,
                          menuMaxHeight: 300,
                          isExpanded: true,
                          value: _selectedFolder,
                          hint: Center(
                              child: Text(
                            AppLocalizations.of(context)!
                                .text_upload_video_select_category,
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: AppColors.TERTIARY_COLOR,
                                fontSize: 14,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                          )),
                          style: TextStyle(
                              color: AppColors.TERTIARY_COLOR,
                              fontSize: 14,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                          onChanged: (value) {
                            setState(() {
                              if (_selectedFolder == null) {
                                _description.text += ' #' + value!.name;
                              } else {
                                _description.text = _description.text
                                    .replaceAll(
                                        _selectedFolder!.name, value!.name);
                              }
                              _selectedFolder = value;
                            });
                          },
                          onSaved: (value) {
                            setState(() {
                              _selectedFolder = value;
                            });
                          },
                          dropdownColor: Colors.black,
                          items: snapshot.data!
                              .map<DropdownMenuItem<DocumentsFolder>>((value) {
                            return DropdownMenuItem<DocumentsFolder>(
                              value: value,
                              child: Center(
                                child: Text(value.name),
                              ),
                            );
                          }).toList(),
                        ),
                      );
                    } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                      return Text("${snapshot.error}");
                    }
                    return Text(
                        AppLocalizations.of(context)!
                            .text_upload_video_loading_categories,
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 15));
                  },
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 20),
                buttonPost(),
                SizedBox(height: 30),
                Container(
                  child: Center(
                      child: Text(
                    progress,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.black,
                    ),
                  )),
                ),
                Visibility(
                    child: Container(
                        child: Center(
                      child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                    )),
                    visible: isInProgress),
                Visibility(
                    child: Container(
                        child: Center(
                      child: Icon(
                        Icons.check,
                        size: 36,
                        color: AppColors.TERTIARY_COLOR,
                      ),
                    )),
                    visible: isFinish)
              ],
            )));
  }```
````

Comment: Did you try Border property with OutlineInputBorder?

Comment: Yes I tried but it only puts a border on my select and not on the expanded part